# Inner Product Proof with Multiplication and Division?

Tags: inner-products

[Problem 10-7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wk7A.png)

Here's a question that appears on my homework (shown in the image above). I'm stuck on how to prove part a). I don't know what to make of the highlighted part. Inner product division and multiplication??

$$\langle v-p,w\rangle\\
= \left\langle v-\left(\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\langle w,w\rangle}w\right),w\right\rangle \ \ \ \ \ \text{By substitution of p}\\
= \langle v,w\rangle-\left\langle\left(\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\langle w,w\rangle}w\right),w\right\rangle \ \ \ \ \ \text{By property (iii)}\\
\text{...}\\
=0$$

After that, I don't know what to do about the division and multiplication of the inner product while still keeping it general and using variables.

Edit: And I know you can multiply w through via property (iv), but I don't know what good that will do.

Comment: Note that $\langle cw,w\rangle = c\langle w,w\rangle$ where $c$ is any scalar. Apply this property with $c = \langle v,w \rangle / \langle w,w \rangle$. No need to be intimidated by the division $\langle v,w \rangle / \langle w,w \rangle$: this is just the quotient of two scalars, hence a scalar.

Comment: The result of an inner product is just a scalar. You can multiply by scalars and divide by nonzero scalars.

Answer (score 1):

After posting this question, I linked it to someone else and they explained it to me. I believe this is the correct answer and I'll lay it out here for anyone else:

$$\langle v-p,w\rangle\\
= \left\langle v-\left(\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\langle w,w\rangle}w\right),w\right\rangle\\
= \langle v,w\rangle-\left\langle\left(\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\langle w,w\rangle}w\right),w\right\rangle\\
= <v,w>-(\frac{<v,w>}{<w,w>})<w,w>\\
= <v,w>-(\frac{<v,w><w,w>}{<w,w>})\\
= <v,w>-<v,w>\\
= 0$$

Comment: Looks mostly OK, except you have some extra angle brackets on lines 4 and 5. This expression on line 4 doesn't make sense: $$\langle(\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\langle w,w \rangle} ) \rangle$$ and there is a similar problem with the second term on line 5.

Comment: Looks good now. :-)